# Delete elements in a vector using a list of iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets suppose I have a unsorted list of iterators to delete defined as

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>  _unsortedIterList;
```

Of another vector defined as:

```
std::vector<int> _listValues;
```

Then this code will not work (since erasing will invalidate the remaining iterators).

```
for ( auto it: _unsortedIterList)
{
   _listValues.erase(it);
}
```

Is there a way to erase all of the iterators properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erasing invalidates iterators at or after the point of erase. So all you have to do is ensure that we erase back to front:

```
// because random access iterators are comparable
std::sort(_unsortedIterList.begin(), _unsortedIterList.end(),
    std::greater<>{});

// now this is back-to-front, so each erase will keep every other iterator valid
for (auto it : _unsortedIterList) {
    _listValues.erase(it);
}
```